# Can't display multiple mysql query results in a html table

Tags: php, mysql

So my problem is that in the MySqL table that i have the values: "minas" and "subject" might be doubled but the comment" value will be different. How can i display in the table all the rows that have the same "subject" and "minas" values and not the last one only?

*Also, if you have any further comments on my way of writing the code feel free to correct me*

In case your having trouble understanding here are some photos:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvncS.jpg

***This is my Code (PHP and html combined)***

```
<?php

include 'dbconn.php';

 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

   $subject = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mathima']));
   $month = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['minas']));

   $sql = "SELECT subject, month, comment FROM mathimata WHERE subject = '$subject' AND month = '$month'";

   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   $noresult = "Δεν έχει καταχωρηθεί το συγκεκριμένο μάθημα";

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $comment =  $row["comment"];
              }
            }
          }
  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="el">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>E•Pagkrition</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet" >

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Αποτελέσματα αναζήτησης</h2>
        <p>Εδώ είναι το μάθημα που επέλεξες</p>
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Μάθημα</th>
              <th>Μήνας</th>
              <th>Περιγραφή</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo "$subject"; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo "$month"; ?></td>
          <td><?php if (isset($comment)) {
            echo $comment;
          } else {
            echo $noresult;
          }?></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At a basic level you could just append to your `$comment` variable instead of overwriting it each time. eg: 
`$comment .=  $row["comment"];`

Comment: You may want to put some kind of separators between them also

Comment: You can initialize an empty array outside your loop and in your loop you can save all the items inside it .

Comment: @Andy Thanks for ypur answer!  That would be usefull but i want it to list in the table as a separate line, one under the other, like a "new" result. The strange thing is that when i echo "$comment" it prints them the way i wated to be, but in a table, it only shows the first one.

Comment: @AmrAly could you write an example for me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, this is your scenario,

you are looping over the database results , then define the result to the same variable every time.

so instead of storing values in a single variable and append it's value in every iterate, you will need to store it in an array like this :

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each
    $comments = [];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $comments[] =  $row["comment"];
    }
}
```

then in your table , iterate over your comments array and build your html like this :

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    $template = '';
    $template .= '<tr>';
    $template .= '<td>' . $subject . '</td>';
    $template .= '<td>' . $month . '</td></td>';
    if (isset($comment)) {
        $template .= $comment;
    } else {
        $template .= $noresult;
    }
    $template .= '</td></tr>';
    echo $template;
}
```

Comment: Why do the first loop at all? `fetch_all()` can do that without the loop.

Comment: +1 Worked. Had to make some changes to the html concatenation you did: $template .= '<td>' . $comment . '</td></td>'; (So it appeared vertically in the table area) and not just  $template .= $comment;

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an empty array outside your loop and in your loop you can save all the items inside it for example.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // initialize your array here 
        $comments = [];
        // output data of each
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $comments[] =  $row["comment"]; // save your values inside the array
    }
 }
```

**and in your view you can loop through the array and echo the values.**

```
foreach($comments as $comment) {
 // echo your values here
  echo $comment
}
```

but what i think  the best answer is [Xorifelse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4982088/xorifelse)'s answer.

Comment: And now we need to loop through the values [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820615/cant-display-multiple-mysql-query-results-in-a-html-table/42820909#comment72753733_42820881). Also, you're not adding in the date and subject.

Answer (score 0):

Directly incorperating the loop into the html can be done like so:

```
<tbody>
  <?php
    // you should execute your query here.
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>', $row['subject'], '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $row['month'],   '</td>';
        echo '<td>', $row['comment'], '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
      }
    }
 ?>
</tbody>
```

This is more or less a working example, but you might only want to print the table if there are actual results. Meaning that you should only print the html table inside the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks,i tried what ypu told me and it works but i would also like to display the results one under the other. In my case they are horizontally listed. What should i do?

Comment: Whoops, i forgot to add the `tr` elements inside the loop, updated.